# Site stores cookie name and user id in script tag after login. Is this an issue for either xss or session highjack?

Tags: xss, javascript, session-management

Upfront I will say that this is not my website and that I am simply doing a general audit (for non security issues), but ran across this in the source after logging in. Another script tag for analytics has the logged in users email address which happens to be the username for logging into the system. Is having this information potentially an issue, and if so how can I create a test to show this; notably the session id based on the session name?

I want to be responsible in disclosing this, if indeed it is an issue. My first attempt was appending a basic script alert window to the url grab some of the data but the url was sanitized by the system.

```
<script>
        var USER = {
            Name: "John Doe",
            idSubject: "5555",
            isLoggedIn: "5555"
        };

        // handle condition for user logged in
        USER.isLoggedIn = (USER.isLoggedIn !== "") ? USER.isLoggedIn : false;


        var APP_PATH = "somesite.com";
        var USE_CACHE = "1";
        var FRAMEWORK_PATH = "somesite.com/framework";
        var DEBUG_MODE = 0;
        var APP_TIMEZONE = "EST";
        var COOKIE_NAME = "FOO_SESS";
    </script>
```

Comment: I would start here:https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Testing_Project

Answer (score 2):

No, including the cookie name or username in the page is not an issue.

The session/cookie name is not secret information, everybody can see it. [Including the content of the cookie on the other hand would be a minor problem, as session cookies are generally supposed to be httpOnly to mitigate some of the risks of XSS].

The users email address also should not be a problem, as it isn't really that sensitive, and can likely be accessed somewhere else anyways (eg via the profile page).

<sub>Your main question seemed to be if including these two pieces of information in the page is a problem. Regarding the other question: We can't really answer if you have an XSS vulnerability without knowing how the user input is actually sanitized by the system.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the fast response this is good to know. I was digging deeper and checked the cookie and it is set to expire at end of session. It looks like the session id is the same before and after login, according to other pages here that could be an issue for session fixation?

Comment: @Shawn session fixation is a problem when the user can set the session id. But yes, it is generally recommended to regenerate the session id when the session state changes, to mitigate the damage of session fixation.